# algorithm to find at least one schedule permutation?

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I have n tasks, each with several possible start times and 1 duration.  If it is possible, I want to find at least one schedule for the n tasks.  I'm trying to build a mobile app just to learn android, so the algorithm efficiency isn't that important.  I would like it to be easy to understand though.  Here's an example:

1. Attend cooking class(50 min): 8am, 12:30pm
2. Watch movie with friend(2 hrs): 2:50pm
3. Walk dog(30 min): 8am, 9am
4. Take nap(1.5 hrs): 1:20pm, 4:30pm
5. Practice java(3 hrs): 8:30am, 11:30am, 2pm, 5pm
6. Practice guitar(1 hr): 11:30am,

The algorithm would return:
walk dog(8am), then practice java(8:30am), then practice guitar(11:30am), then attend cooking class(12:30pm), then take nap(1:20pm), then watch movie with friend(2:50pm).

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to research such an algorithm yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Brute force would be simplest.  For the example you list, there are 32 possible arrangements:  2x1x2x2x4x1.  Just iterate through all of them.  You need a data structure that allows you to represent a given specific schedule choice, and to check for time overlap among the appointments in the schedule.  A list of "appointments" (however you want to represent that; array, dict, whatever) would do it.  Sort the list in chronological order of appointment start, then check each one to see if it collides with the next.
[Edited for detail, clarity]

Comment: 32 arrangements?  Overlap?  Please elaborate.

Comment: @HukeLau_DABA He did elaborate - 32 = 2x1x2x2x4x1.  He also explained it another way - "Just iterate through all of them."